# Can you use the Sorcerer's Extended Spell Metamagic option with the Delayed Blast Fireball spell to get an extra 10d6 damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic

The Sorcerer can get the Metamagic, Extended Spell.

Extended Spell (PHB p. 102)

> When you Cast a Spell that has a Duration of 1 minute or longer, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double its Duration, to a maximum Duration of 24 hours.

Delayed Blast Fireball (PHB p. 230-231)

> ...The spell's base damage is 12d6. If at the end of your turn the bead has not yet detonated, the damage increases by 1d6...

Extended Spell would extend the spell duration to up to 2 minutes. This would add a possible ten more rounds which would be 10d6 damage.

**Is this possible for only 1 sorcery point?** This would make the damage from a full duration delayed blast fireball 32d6 (192) or an average of 112 damage.

Comment: Keep in mind it would take an extra 10 rounds to charge up, which might not be great if you're in the middle of combat.

Comment: @GreySage Yes but imagine blowing up a building for an assassination. Oh, it would be sweet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes

[Delayed Blast Fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/delayed-blast-fireball) states that you can hold it for its duration:

> A beam of yellow light flashes from your pointing finger, then condenses to linger at a chosen point within range as a glowing bead **for the duration**.
>
> ...
>
> If at the end of your turn the bead has not yet detonated, **the damage increases by 1d6**

Double the duration to 2 minutes, and that is another 10 of your turns you can hold it for, giving an extra 10d6 damage.

Comment: One might add that this is not as overpowered as the OP seems to think: While it potentially adds a lot of damage, being able to actually afford waiting two minutes (20 rounds in combat) is far from feasible most of the time.

Comment: @MarsPlastic Delayed Blast Fireball actually ticks at the end of each of your turns, so with something like Time Stop it can tick multiple times per round.

Comment: @Medix2 Mechanically even "1 turn" vs "1 round" is very different to me. I have changed it to "10 of your turns", but I don't agree with changing it to rounds. There is no "technically correct", only "correct".